# Sharing the network between 2 VMware hosts

Tags: networking, vmware-server, share

I have 2 linux servers which do run VMware server.
My question about this is it possible to create a shared NAT/host-only network for the 2 VMware servers so that the VMware guest of both servers are on the same internal network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear but I assume you want a network between both hosts that will allow guests to speak between themselves but not out past the hosts - is that right?

If so then all you just need to create a network that's shared between hosts and ensure it has no route outside, it's a switch/router thing really rather than a vmware thing.